# popToRootViewControllerAnimated does not display root view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I need a little help on a problem with navigation controllers.

I have a `navigationController` with 4 `ViewControllers` pushed. The last vc I push presents a further `ViewController` modally. The modal `ViewController` presents an `ActionSheet`. Depending on the user's answer I either dismiss the modal `ViewController` only or I want to go back to the root `ViewController`.

In the `ViewController` presented modally I have:

```
- (void) dismissGameReport
{    
    [[self delegate] GameReportModalWillBeDismissed:modalToPopToRoot];    
}
```

In the last `ViewController` pushed onto the `navigationController` stack I have:

```
- (void)GameReportModalWillBeDismissed: (BOOL)popToRoot;
{    
    if (popToRoot) 
        {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    else 
        {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }            
}
```

Dismissing the modal view controller works fine. 
However,

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

does not cause the root `ViewController` to display its views. Adding some log info I see that after the message to `self.navigationController` the stack is correctly popped but execution continues sequentially. The screen still shows the view of the modal ViewController.

As a workaround I tried always dismissing the modal view controller and in the `ViewWillAppear` method have the `popToRootAnimated` message. No difference. Still the stack of controllers is popped but the screen continues showing my modal view controller's view and execution continues sequentially.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: have you try to debug with break point that your compiler go into if loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like these deceptive questions. It seems very simple, until you try to do it.

What I found was that basically you do need to dismiss that modal view controller, but if you try to pop from the navigation controller on the next line things get mixed up. You must ensure the dismiss is complete before attempting the pop. In iOS 5 you can use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` like so.

```
-(void)GameReportModalWillBeDismissed:(BOOL)popToRoot{    
    if (popToRoot){
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];
    }
    else{
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }            
}
```

But I see you have 4.0 in your question tags. The solution I found for `<iOS 5` is far less pretty but should still work, and it sounds like you were already on the trail. You want `viewDidAppear:` not `viewWillAppear:`. My solution here involves an ivar, lets say:

```
BOOL shouldPopToRootOnAppear;
```

And then your `GameReportModalWillBeDismissed:` would look something like this:

```
-(void)GameReportModalWillBeDismissed:(BOOL)popToRoot{    
    shouldPopToRootOnAppear = popToRoot;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];          
}
```

And your `viewDidAppear:` would look like this...

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (shouldPopToRootOnAppear){
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }
    // Normal viewDidAppear: stuff here
}
```

Comment: hello. Great !!! It worked like a charm. Thanks so much, it was more than 4 days I was fiddling around with my code. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Glad to help. If this answer solved your problem your problem you should accept it.